# Get The Exact Element That Was Clicked In jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have a `UL` list and I want to change the class of each the element clicked.. easy enough but when I use sub categories? `ul` lists within `li` elements and use code like this:

```
<ul class="options">
    <li>option 1</li>
    <li>option 2
        <ul>
            <li>option 2.1</li>
            <li>option 2.2</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
<script>
$(".options li").click(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass("chose");
});
</script>
```

And a lot of CSS to take care of the rest.

It changes the class of the main `li` element that the `ul` list is hosted in but I only want it to change the class of the exact element in the sub list.

How could I do this so that the parent `li` class does not change but only the actual list item clicked. But also allow the parent `li` element to be selected directly too?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use jQuery's [`stopPropagation()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/) function on the event object passed in:

```
$(".options li").click(function(event){
  $(this).toggleClass("chose");
  event.stopPropagation();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/42vsE/

That way the event will only fire for the element that was clicked, and won't bubble up to the parent `<li>`.

Comment: add the .chose class in jsFiddle.  Works fine  .chose {color:red}

Comment: this is incorrect, if u click option 2, it turns the children red as well

Comment: @JohnnyCraig: That's a non-issue, the classes are applied correctly using the jQuery...it's the CSS that would need to change to stop all of the children of the parent `<li>` from turning red, e.g. `li.chose li {color:black;}`

Comment: I wasn't aware of stopPropagation

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
$(".options li ul li").click(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    var parentli = $this.parent().parent();

    $this.toggleClass("chose");
    parentli.doSomething();
});
</script>
```

should work just fine.

Comment: yes but this won't now work for elements immediately below .options

Comment: @griegs I guess the question confuses me.  I thought he DOESN'T want to target elements directly below `.options`?